# Trying to refine an SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an assignment where I am working with a fictional hotel database. I am trying to write a query to "Find bookings for a guest who has booked two rooms for the same dates."

I have a `guest` table that lists the guests. A guest can have 0 or more reservations

```
hotel7=# SELECT * FROM guest;
 guest_id |  name   |    phone     |     email     
----------+---------+--------------+---------------
    1 | kat     | 111-111-1111 | kat@g.com
    2 | andy    | 222-222-2222 | andy@g.com
    3 | theda   | 333-333-3333 | theda@g.com
    4 | forrest | 444-444-4444 | forrest@g.com
    5 | trent   | 555-555-5555 | trent@g.com
    6 | cyle    | 666-666-6666 | cyle@g.com
(6 rows)
```

I have a `reservation` table listing all the reservations. Each reservation has one guest and can be associated with 1 or more rooms.

```
hotel7=# SELECT * FROM reservation;
 res_id | guest_id |  check_in  | check_out  
--------+----------+------------+------------
  1 |        1 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-03
  2 |        1 | 2017-12-05 | 2017-12-07
  3 |        2 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-02
  4 |        2 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-10
  5 |        3 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-10
  6 |        4 | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-30
  7 |        5 | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-22
(7 rows)
```

And a `room_res` table that shows what rooms belong to what reservations

```
hotel7=# SELECT * FROM room_res;
 res_id | room_id 
--------+---------
  1 |       1
  1 |       2
  2 |       1
  3 |       3
  3 |       4
  4 |       5
  5 |       6
  6 |       1
  7 |       3
(9 rows)
```

This command gets me close, but I only want to show people that have booked 2 or more rooms with a reservation.

```
hotel7=# SELECT g.name, r.res_id, r.check_in, r.check_out, rr.room_id
FROM guest AS g
INNER JOIN reservation AS r
ON r.guest_id = g.guest_id
INNER JOIN room_res AS rr
ON rr.res_id = r.res_id;
  name   | res_id |  check_in  | check_out  | room_id 
---------+--------+------------+------------+---------
 kat     |      1 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-03 |       1
 kat     |      1 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-03 |       2
 kat     |      2 | 2017-12-05 | 2017-12-07 |       1
 andy    |      3 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-02 |       3
 andy    |      3 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-02 |       4
 andy    |      4 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-10 |       5
 theda   |      5 | 2017-12-01 | 2017-12-10 |       6
 forrest |      6 | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-30 |       1
 trent   |      7 | 2017-12-15 | 2017-12-22 |       3
(9 rows)
```

So I tried this and came up empty

```
hotel7=#  SELECT g.name, r.res_id, r.check_in, r.check_out, rr.room_id
FROM guest AS g
INNER JOIN reservation AS r
ON r.guest_id = g.guest_id
INNER JOIN room_res AS rr
ON rr.res_id = r.res_id GROUP BY g.name, r.res_id, r.check_in, r.check_out, 
rr.room_id
HAVING COUNT (rr.room_id)>1;
 name | res_id | check_in | check_out | room_id 
------+--------+----------+-----------+---------
(0 rows)
```

Comment: Your query with group by and having is more or less correct. Your problem is that you are grouping with room_id. The thing is that you don't want the room_id in the group because it is doing all the rows diferents and for this reason you don't have any row duplicated and the having doen't get anything. You have to remove room_id of all your query (select and group by) and change the having count for count(*) for example. And the res_id in the group by also can you remove it, because is possible that one customer will make 2 reservations in the same days but a with a different reservation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `rr.room_id` from the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` lists.

```
SELECT g.name, r.res_id, r.check_in, r.check_out
FROM guest AS g
INNER JOIN reservation AS r ON r.guest_id = g.guest_id
INNER JOIN room_res AS rr ON rr.res_id = r.res_id 
GROUP BY g.name, r.res_id, r.check_in, r.check_out
HAVING COUNT (rr.room_id)>1;
```

When you group by the room, too, you've limited the potential size of each group to one room, and you'll never be able to have a COUNT(room_id) > 1.

However, that's the simple version of the problem. It only works if you can assume reservation dates line up exactly, and if you take a loose reading of the problem statement. If you need to allow for reservations where check_in/check_out dates don't much up, things get much more complicated. Here's how I'd handle that:

1. Generate a numbers table (Google this if you don't know how.)
2. Join from the `Reservation` table to the generated numbers table where the number value is less than the `DATEDIFF()` between `check_in` and `check_out`
3. Use this date result instead of the `check_in` and `check_out` columns in your GROUP BY expression.

Additionally, the problem statement asks you to find bookings for guests who have booked two rooms on the same day. The statement does **NOT** limit you to just the multiple room bookings; a strict reading of the problem would find **ALL** bookings for a guest if the guest has *any* bookings meeting this criteria.

Taking that into account, and assuming you already have a Numbers table, the full query would look like this:

```
WITH EligibleGuests As (   
    SELECT r.guest_id
    FROM reservation r
    INNER JOIN Numbers n ON n.Number < DATEDIFF(d, r.check_in, r.check_out) 
    INNER JOIN room_res AS rr ON rr.res_id = r.res_id 
    GROUP BY r.guest_id, DATEADD(d, r.check_in, n.Number)
    HAVING COUNT (rr.room_id)>1
)
SELECT g.name, r.check_in, r.check_out, rr.room_id
FROM Guests g
INNER JOIN EligibleGuests eg on eg.guest_id = g.guest_id
INNER JOIN Reservations r ON r.guest_id = g.guest_ID
INNER JOIN Room_Res rr on rr.res_id = r.res_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this boils down to an overlapping range problem in disguise.  We can try self joining the `reservation` table to check for an overlapping reservation range also resulting in two or more reserved rooms.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT r1.guest_id
    FROM reservation r1
    INNER JOIN room_res rr1
        ON r1.res_id = rr1.res_id
    INNER JOIN reservation r2
        ON r1.check_in < r2.check_out AND
           r1.check_out > r2.check_in AND
           r1.guest_id = r2.guest_id  AND
           r1.res_id < r2.res_id
    INNER JOIN room_res rr2
        ON r2.res_id = rr2.res_id
    WHERE
        rr1.room_id <> rr2.room_id
)

SELECT g.*
FROM guest g
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON g.guest_id = t.guest_id;
```

[image]

### Demo